# "Fixing" Corrupt Sectors in Disk Image

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I used ddrescue ( via the gddrescue package ) to create a disk image of a full 1.5TB drive that had multiple partitions. That completed fine using.

```
ddrescue --no-split /dev/sd{X} /path/to/drive.img /path/to/drive.log
```

I'm able to see both partitions fine via fdisk against the img:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb65b52a6

Device            Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
DiskImg.img1 *          2048 1933981695 1933979648 922.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
DiskImg.img2      1933981696 2930272255  996290560 475.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I'm also able to mount the partitions and see the files that were on the drive fine without an issue using the offset option when mounting.

The issue I'm running into is that while trying to copy the files from the image to a new drive, the process completely stops at some point. I presume where the bad sectors were on the old drive.

I know the bad/missing sectors are copied in a sense, but I thought I would be able to easily get the data that wasn't bad/missing. Is that not the case? I can't find any options within the copy command that would skip errors, etc and the option --ignore-errors in rsync doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a utility that will let me copy whatever files are available without locking everything up once a file is hit with a bad sector? I'd really like to avoid using something like safecopy to copy from the image I created to a new image as I'd have to purchase another drive on top of the one I already have to recover this data.

So far it appears that the following might work:

```
rsync -avP --stats --block-size=512 --timeout=10 /path/to/src /path/to/dest
```

Although the timeout seems to be a lot longer than 10 seconds.

Comment: It seems you already know how to use `rsync`. What is the question exactly? :)